# Graphics.DrawRectangle Missing edge on 2nd screen

Tags: .net, winforms, windows-8.1, gdi+, system.drawing

I'm trying to draw a variable colour/width border on a form (for 'across the room' status reporting) it draws fine except when maximised on non-primary displays...

When maximised on a 2nd display I don't get the left most edge drawn as shown [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFIdh.png) (Green rect added for debug, and always appears to draw ok).

I've tried numerous permutations of draw sequence, +/-1 pixel here and there, changing pen properties etc.. but nothing seems to work and the fact it works non maximised everywhere and maximised on primary screens makes me think it's something a bit more subtle.

Complete code to reproduce is (Single size-able form with single button):

```
Public Class Form2
Private DrawHighlightingRectangle As Boolean = False
Private HighlightingRectangleColour As Color = Color.Red

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If DrawHighlightingRectangle Then
        Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(HighlightingRectangleColour, 8)
        myPen.Alignment = Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset

        e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 0, 0, Me.ClientRectangle.Width, Me.ClientRectangle.Height)

        myPen.Color = Color.Green
        '    e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, 0, 0, 0, 100)
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100)

        myPen.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    Me.Invalidate()
    Me.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DrawHighlightingRectangle = Not DrawHighlightingRectangle
    Me.Invalidate()
    Me.Update()
End Sub
End Class
```

Debug of x,y and Me.ClientRectangle (It should be ClientRectangle I'm using, right?) sizes confirm they're correct.

Any ideas?

EDIT:

Changed Me.ClientRectangle.Width to a var for a bit more in-depth debug, new complete code is;

```
Public Class Form2
Private DrawHighlightingRectangle As Boolean = False
Private HighlightingRectangleColour As Color = Color.Red
Private MyWidth = 1900

Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
    If DrawHighlightingRectangle Then
        Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(HighlightingRectangleColour, 8)

        e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)

        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 0, 0, MyWidth, Me.ClientRectangle.Height)

        myPen.Color = Color.Green
        e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(myPen, 0, 0, 100, 100)

        myPen.Dispose()
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
    Me.Invalidate()
    Me.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    DrawHighlightingRectangle = Not DrawHighlightingRectangle
    Me.Invalidate()
    Me.Update()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    MyWidth += 1
    Me.Invalidate()
    Me.Update()
End Sub
End Class
```

(Remember to change MyWidth from 1900 to match your set-up!)

Using this approach I can increment the width and watch the rect grow, however when nearing the correct full width the left edge disappears - changing the pen width affects when at which point it will disappear (I removed the Pen.Alignment = Inset in-case that was an issue) but either way I cannot get my desired output...

Comment: One thing you are doing wrong is assuming that you line starts at the location you specified. That location is the middle of the line you are creating/ If it is 8 wide, you need to buffer by half that width.

Comment: That's the reason I was originally using `Pen.Alignment = Alignment.Inset` but after reading [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.pen.alignment(v=vs.110).aspx) the remarks section states 'A Pen that has its alignment set to Inset will yield unreliable results, sometimes...' so I dropped it for the 2nd example. Using the default Pen properties (Alignment=Center) does indeed cut part of the line but the overall problem still exists, as I increase the width of the rect eventually the left edge will not be drawn. Can anyone repro this behaviour?

Comment: It happens to me too. I have 3 monitors and it happens on my primary but not the other 2. Very strange. I have not been able to figure it out what is happening.

Comment: Possible twist on off-by-one error.  Wonder if some part of the draw code pushes the left edge off the secondary display and therefore it gets clipped?  Width -1 instead of width?  (Or screen width - pen width)

Comment: Why MyWitdh instead of Me.ClientRectangle.Width?  Is that just for incremental testing?

Comment: Yes added the `MyWidth` variable to allow manual control for debugging, I can get the rect on screen then increase width by 1px at a time - as the width approaches the `ClientRectangle.Width` value all of a sudden the left edge will disappear and you'll have an incomplete rectangle. Basically if (rect width > (client width - pen width)) I can't seem to draw the left edge when location = (0,0), if I move the x-location to greater than pen width (i.e. (x,y)(10,0)) it draws the left edge but this isn't where I want it!

Comment: Quick test on Win7 Enterprise, using just Me.ClientRectangle.Width I see the same behavior.  Interestingly, this seems dependent on primary  monitor, not left (or Main) monitor,

Comment: Sorry to pile on the comments with more info, but haven't solved the problem, so not an answer yet.  The Pen is being clipped on all boundaries, as you can see if you set x greater than width of the pen instead of 0, the left edge line is thicker than the other edges.  I suspect there is some weird clipping logic that goes on the shared edge between displays.  Is X=0 on display 2 the same location as X=width on display 1 and therefore clipped?

Comment: If it was being clipped I would have expected to see the line drop-off 1px at a time but a 1px increase in width can result in losing an entire 8px wide line in one increment. I'll try using monitors in a vertical arrangement when I get in tonight to see if I can get similar behaviour for top or bottom edges...

Comment: This article provides some insight to window rectangles for the Maximized state, https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20120326-00/?p=8003.  Possibly combine that with fuzzy logic around the shared edge for multiple displays?

Comment: I've had a play about again and think I've stumbled into GDI+ more than .net - I don't think it's limited to the maximised window state any longer - changing monitor layout in windows results in widely varied behaviour. (it still never works correctly on anything but primary screen!) If I increase the pen width to exacerbate the effect I can see it only ever affects left and top edges regardless of monitor location but can also occur in normal window state by putting the 2nd monitor on RHS of primary and drag a normal window's left edge toward the primary monitor - it'll clip a Pen.Width away!

Comment: GDI+ internally uses floating point and suffers from the inevitable rounding errors that this causes.  For pixel-perfect line drawing you always want to change the Graphics.PixelOffsetMode to Half.

Comment: Just tried that but still getting the same behaviour. I have narrowed the issue down even further; If the rectangle comes within a `Pen.Width` of a shared edge on _any_ side that rectangle will clip a `Pen.Width` away from the left edge of the screen if the window/rectangle is close enough (maximised or not). (Only tested with shared edges involving primary monitor, i.e. not stacked triple monitor). I'll try to avoid spamming the comments by editing the q tomorrow after a more structured testing regime. As a cheap work-around I can draw nested FillRectangle() to create the desired effect :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug. For a workaround, when you are full screened on a non primary screen, you should have  `TopLeft=Pen.Width-1`. In all other cases the rectangle needs to have `TopLeft=CInt(Math.Floor(Pen.Width/2))`. Make sure to adjust the width of the rectangle accordingly

Also, I noticed that you cannot draw to the Left margin with a pen wider than 1 pixel. Play around with the below sample code

```
Public Class Form1
    Private DrawHighlightingRectangle As Boolean = True
    Private HighlightingRectangleColour As Color = Color.Red
    Private PenWidth = 1
    Dim myPen As New System.Drawing.Pen(HighlightingRectangleColour, PenWidth)

    Dim x = 0

    Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Text = "Pen Width = " & PenWidth & ", X = " & x
        myPen.Alignment = Drawing2D.PenAlignment.Inset
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Paint(sender As Object, e As PaintEventArgs) Handles Me.Paint
        If DrawHighlightingRectangle Then
            e.Graphics.Clear(Me.BackColor)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, x, 100, x, 200)
            e.Graphics.DrawLine(myPen, CInt(Math.Floor(PenWidth / 2)), 10, CInt(Math.Floor(PenWidth / 2)), 100)
        End If
    End Sub

    Private Sub Form1_Resize(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Resize
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click ' draw button
        DrawHighlightingRectangle = Not DrawHighlightingRectangle
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click ' Move Right
        x += 1
        Text = "Pen Width = " & PenWidth & ", X = " & x
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click ' increase pen width
        PenWidth += 1
        myPen.Dispose()
        myPen = New System.Drawing.Pen(HighlightingRectangleColour, PenWidth)
        Text = "Pen Width = " & PenWidth & ", X = " & x
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click ' reset width and X
        PenWidth = 1
        x = 0
        myPen.Dispose()
        myPen = New System.Drawing.Pen(HighlightingRectangleColour, PenWidth)
        Text = "Pen Width = " & PenWidth & ", X = " & x
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Button5_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button5.Click ' Move Left
        x -= 1
        Text = "Pen Width = " & PenWidth & ", X = " & x
        Me.Invalidate()
        Me.Update()
    End Sub
End Class
```